# Reference list index to enumerate value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, enumerate

I have a program which checks an outlook inbox for attachments from specific senders in a dictionary. [Python - Outlook search emails within specific range only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282293/python-outlook-search-emails-within-specific-range-only)

That program works fine, and now I'm trying to expand on it by giving the user the ability to choose a specific sender from the dictionary, so as to only search their emails. This code is within the previous program.

The dictionary I have is `senderDict = {sender@address.com : Sender Name}`

To turn it into a menu of values to choose from I've used enumerate:

```
listSender = list(senderDict.values())

for count, item in enumerate(listSender,1):
    print(count, item)

print("There are", len(listSender), "items.")

while True:
    senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))        
    try:
        if senderNum <= len(listSender) and senderNum >= 0:
            #senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))
            print("you chose", listSender[senderNum])
            break

        elif senderNum == 0:
            print("Searching for any sender")
            break

        elif senderNum < 0:
            print("Cannot choose a negative number.")
            continue

    except ValueError: #Not int
        print("You did not enter a valid number (ValueError)")
        input()

    except IndexError: #outside range
        print("You did not enter a valid number (IndexError)")
        input()
```

The issue is that choosing zero will choose the zero index, instead of 'search any'. How do I make the list index match the enumerate values?

Also, entering a non-number or blank input crashes the program, so I'm not certain what exception covers that, I thought it fell under ValueError.

I'm not really sure if I even need to turn the dictionary into a list, but I had read that it was necessary for enumerate to work so I just went with it.

Comment: @shyamzzp “which” in this context is correct. Please don’t perform spurious changes based on stylistic preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the helpful responses!

Instead of trying to change the value of the input, I decided to insert a list option for 'Search Any' after converting the dictionary to a list, then let enumerate start from zero. This way I don't have to do any addition or subtraction and the index values still match the input.

```
listSender = list(senderDict.values())
listSender.insert(0, "Search Any")

for count, item in enumerate(listSender):
    print(count, item)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems you have a little bug in your code!

```
if senderNum <= len(listSender) and senderNum >= 0:
```

The above line includes 0. `0 >= 0 == True` therefore

```
elif senderNum == 0:
```

will never be reached since it is already reached in the previous if statement. I believe what you wanted to do is

```
if senderNum <= len(listSender) and senderNum > 0:
```

This way the above line will be False when the chosen number is 0 and the elif line will be reached by your code. If you need it to match an index in your list, since you set your enumerate to start at 1 you can manually subtract 1 from the user's chosen value `count - 1`.

In order to catch incorrect values you could add an else statement:

```
else:
    print('Incorrect value')
    continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is how to list index match the enumerate values. That is quite easy you only have to subtract 1 from the input your user provides you. The problem is in your if clause `senderNum >= 0` that will be true if your user inputs 0 so the `elif senderNum == 0` will never be true

For your crash when you enter a non-number that happens because you have the `try` after the conversion of the entry into an int. So you have to put the try befor the `int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))`

My suggestion is rather to choose negative number for sending to any.

So my suggestion is the following:

```
listSender = list(senderDict.values())

for count, item in enumerate(listSender):
        print(count, item)

print("There are", len(listSender), "items.")

while True:
    try:  # have to be before the int(input(...)) to catch the exception
        senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (-1 for any): "))        

        if senderNum < len(listSender) and senderNum >= 0: # len(listSender) is not allowed because the index starts at 0 and the last entry is len(listSender) -1                    
            print("you chose", listSender[senderNum])
            break

        elif senderNum < 0:
            print("Search for any sender")
            break

    except ValueError: #Not int
        print("You did not enter a valid number (ValueError)")
        input()

    except IndexError: #outside range
        print("You did not enter a valid number (IndexError)")
        input()
```

if you really want to use 0 as for send any I then you have to do the following:

```
listSender = list(senderDict.values())

for count, item in enumerate(listSender,1):
        print(count, item) 

print("There are", len(listSender), "items.")

while True:
    try:
        senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))
        if senderNum <= len(listSender) and senderNum > 0: # if senderNum is zero then send for any so senderNum >= 0 has to be changed to senderNum > 0
            print("you chose", listSender[senderNum-1]) # because index starts with 0 you have to subtract 1 from the input
            break

        elif senderNum == 0:
            print("Searching for any sender")
            break

        elif senderNum < 0:
            print("Cannot choose a negative number.")
            continue

    except ValueError: #Not int
        print("You did not enter a valid number (ValueError)")
        input()

    except IndexError: #outside range
        print("You did not enter a valid number (IndexError)")
        input()
```

To address your last question about enumerate and dictionary/list.
A dictionary is not ordered so that is why you can't enumerate through it with an index. So it is necessary to do a conversion into a list. The other way to use it without casting it into a list is to use the dictionary keys as input instead of index numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that choosing zero will choose the zero index, instead of 'search any'. How do I make the list index match the enumerate values?

First fix the order of your tests, then substract 1 from the user's input.

> Also, entering a non-number or blank input crashes the program, so I'm not certain what exception covers that, I thought it fell under ValueError.

`int(something)` can raise either a `TypeError` (if `type(something)` isn't something that can be interpreted as numeric value) or `ValueError` if the type is ok but not the value.

`input()` (`raw_input()` in py2)`always returns a string so you cannot have a`TypeError`eher and`ValueError` is indeed what you want to catch - but you have to put your try/except block at the right place. Currently you have:

```
senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))        
try:
  # use senderNum here
except ValueError:
  # ...
```

but the `ValueError` is raised by `int(...)` so it will indeed not be caught. You want:

```
try:
   senderNum = int(input("Choose a sender (zero for any): "))        
except ValueError:
   print("not a valid value")
   continue

# ok, now `senderNum` is an integer
```

Also since you test that `senderNum` is within boundaries, you should not have any `IndexError`. Well, actually you wouldn't if the test was correct - you should test that `senderNum` is **strictly** smaller than `len(listSender)` - remember that lists are zero-based, so the last index of a list is `len(lst) - 1`:

```
>>> lst = list("abc")
>>> len(lst)
3
>>> 3 <= len(lst)
True
>>> lst[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> 3 < len(lst)
False
>>>
```

> I'm not really sure if I even need to turn the dictionary into a list, but I had read that it was necessary for enumerate to work so I just went with it.

`enumerate()` works on any iterable. A `dict` is an iterable so you could just pass `senderDict` to `enumerate` directly - but then you'd have the keys, not names. Or you could just pass `senderDict.values()` directly, but then you're going to have another issue, which is how to get the email back from the name.

The proper solution here is to turn your dict into a list of `(key, value)` tuples - which is as simple as `list(senderDict.items())`, so you can get both the name and email from the choosen list index.

Corrected code:

```
senders = list(senderDict.items())

# this won't change during execution so let's 
# stop recomputing it each time

nb_senders = len(senders)

for index, (email, name) in enumerate(senders, 1):
    print("{}: {} ({})".format(index, name, email)


print("There are {} items.".format(nb_senders))


while True:
    # get the raw input
    senderNum = input("Choose a sender (zero for any): ")        

    # now validate it
    try:
        senderNum = int(senderNum)
        if senderNum < 0:
            raise ValueError("should not be negative")
        if senderNum > nb_senders:
            raise ValueError("should be lesser than {}".format(nb_senders))

    except ValueError as e:
        print("'{}' is not valid choice: {}".format(senderNum,  e))
        continue

    # ok, done           
    if senderNum == 0:
        print("Searching for any sender")
        break

    print("you chose {} ({})".format(*listSender[senderNum]))
    break
```